# How to validate Test set on trained SVD model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svd

I'm following this tutorial on Matrix Factorization for Movie Recommendations in Python using **Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)**: 
 [here](https://beckernick.github.io/matrix-factorization-recommender/)

Using **SVD**, a dataset is approximated using SVD into three components:
`M ≈ U ⋅ S ⋅ Vt`

- So you go from left (M) to the three components and back again,
- now you can use approx.
- M as a recommendation matrix.

Now, i want to use train/test validation sets on this matrix, because you need to find the optimal k (number) approximation for M.

**How does one apply a separate test set on a trained model to get the predictions for the unseen test set?**
What is the **math / algorithm** for this?
Thanks

Comment: If you search in your browser for "machine learning model train test validate", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

The standard procedure for fitting any machine learning model goes as follows:

- you split your data set randomly to three parts: training set (60% of the data), validation set (20% of the data), test set (20%).
- You use **only** your train data to train any model
- You use your validation set to choose hyperparameters and select the best among different models
- You evaluate your model on test set to get the notion of how it will perform on new unseen data

So in your case the you should perform following steps:

- split the data set to these 3 parts (if you are using sklearn you can use `train_test_split` as in [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/train-test-validation-set-splitting-in-sklearn)
- you run SVD with different values of `k` and evaluate performance of these approximations on the validation set and choose the `k` with the lowest value of RMSE (as stated in the tutorial)
- apply chosen model on test set to see how it may perform on unseen data

If your dataset is small instead of splitting to 3 datasets you can just split to train and test and use [cross validation](https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-validation-explained-evaluating-estimator-performance-e51e5430ff85) to fine tune your `k`.

Comment: Yes i know this. What i'm asking is, how do you 'evaluate performance of these approximations on the validation set' in the case of SVD. How can one apply a test set on a trained SVD matrix?

Comment: I am not sure that I correctly understand your question but you evaluate on validation set by measuring the RMSE. In terms of the second question I understand it as 'how you can apply SVD from your training set to your test set?'. If this is the question then after you calculated your U,S, Vt you do: `X_test_transformed = np.dot(X_test, Vt.T)` as explained [here](http://blog.andersen.im/2016/01/practical-feature-reduction-using-svd-in-r/)

Comment: @StanisławWilczyński, if I understand correctly, one should not have to retrain SVD with different k every time. One can train SVD with k=50, and then one can use the internal matrices to calculate only the first say 10 components (without completely retrain the matrices). For example, see [this tutorial for R](https://www.michalkosinski.com/data-mining-tutorial). The author uses some varimax transformation that I fail to understand and reproduce in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It is not usually written like that but to make it simple, here is how I would answer your question:

`A`<sub>train</sub> matrix is factorized into the product of three matrices:

`A`<sub>train</sub> `= U @ S @ VT`

Once, you decide on your optimal k (number) approximation for A, take the k rank of your decomposed matrices.

`A`<sub>train</sub> `≈ U`<sub>k</sub> `@ S`<sub>k</sub>`@ VT`<sub>k</sub>

To find projections or new coordinates of your train set:

`A`<sub>train</sub> `@ VT`<sub>k</sub>`.T` or `A`<sub>train</sub>`.T @ VT`<sub>k</sub> or `U`<sub>k</sub> `@ S`<sub>k</sub>`

To find projections or new coordinates of your test set:

`A`<sub>test</sub> `@ VT`<sub>k</sub>`.T` or `A`<sub>test</sub>`.T @ VT`<sub>k</sub>

Hope that helps!